# basic and minimal java development setup

Tags: java

I am using Ubuntu and I would like to know the basic tools to install so I can begin develop in java.

With 'minimal' I mean the most transparent way without fancy tools and stacks etc. Like for minimal C programming you just write code and run 'gcc file.c -o myapp'.

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just download [JDK](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1637583.html).

Minimal tools are [javac](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/solaris/javac.html) for compiling and [java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/solaris/java.html) for executing JVM. Both are in bin directory.

Answer (score 2):

[You need to install JDK](http://www.wikihow.com/Create-Your-First-Java-Program-on-Ubuntu-Linux) to start with `hello world`

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse IDE. It's probably the most comprehensive Java IDE. I understand that isn't what you're looking for but light, simple ones like JCreator are not free to use. I don't see the sense in developing without an IDE of any kind.

Comment: I would consider Eclipse a pretty "fancy tool"

Comment: Even though Eclipse is great to have for Java development, it's clearly not what the OP is asking about.

Comment: so would I. Just a suggestion, the most minimal tool is the ubuntu equivalent of notepad.

Comment: 'notepad'?  so as to not start a holy war - pick vi or emacs - neither are the wrong choice

Answer (score 1):

Install the JDK. An IDE is a minimal requirement for development in Java. Not all developers would agree, but IMHO its the most productive way to develop in Java. I suggest IntelliJ CE which is free.

Comment: "most productive" != "minimal" / "most transparent"